# Show Column Name from joined table as header

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in mysql. If I want to use the column name from my Questions table (q in this example) to match with the answers summed, how could I do that? In other words rather than specifying the As column, can I specify the As using the q column IE: As q.column1 etc...?

```
Select q.question, sum(c.answer1+g.answer1) as Answer1,sum(c.answer2+g.answer2) as Answer2
from Questions q
join caggregate c on(q.questionid=c.questionid)
join gaggregate g on (c.questionid=g.questionid)
Group By q.questionid;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Aliases (`AS`) simply rename a field to something else. You cannot use the contents of some OTHER field to fill in as the name of the alias. Not without a bunch of dynamic SQL statement creation.

Comment: So How could I do this with a query? Is it possible or better to handle in my view side?